# Logarithm rules for a ratio and a subtraction

Tags: calculus

I don't know if it's been too long since school, but I just can't get my head around this. If we have the equation $y = \frac{a}{b} - c$ and we were to take the natural logarithm of each side of the equation, we'd have $\mathrm{ln}(y) = \mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{a}{b} - c\right)$. I know that $\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\mathrm{ln}(a)-\mathrm{ln}(b)$, but I don't know how to expand out the former expression. It can't be $\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)-\mathrm{ln}(c)$ because that would be equal to $\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{ac}{b}\right)$, which clearly isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously I don't know what your goal here is so it's hard to say, but you could try getting a common denominator first: $\ln(\frac{a}{b}-c) = \ln(\frac{a}{b}-c\times\frac{b}{b}) = \ln(\frac{a-c\times b}{b}) = \ln(a-c\times b)-\ln(b)$.